# my entity does not update throw a form

Tags: php, symfony, entity, twig, bundle

I have an entity "group", with a name and a description.
I created a form for update both, but when I click on submit, values are set to `NULL`.

I also tried to create a new entity. But in this case, their value are set to default value in the field.

Here's my code :

my form :

```
  <form method="post" class="form-signin" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <input id="name" name="form[name]" required="required" value="{{ group.name }}"></input>
    <textarea id="description" name="form[description]" >{{ group.description }}</textarea>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

my controller :

```
  public function updateParametersAction()
  {
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getManager()
                   ->getRepository('MyBundle:Groups');

    $group = $repository->findOneByIdUser($user->getId());

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($group)
                 ->add('name',        'text')
                 ->add('description', 'textarea')
                 ->getForm();

    $request = $this->get('request');

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {    
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($group);
      $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Client:updateParameters.html.twig', array(
      'group' => $group,
      'form' => $form->createView()
      ));
  }
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind a request to the form:

```
// (...)

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($group)
             ->add('name',        'text')
             ->add('description', 'textarea')
             ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

// (...)
```